# PHP Default Timezone Set

Tags: php, timezone, mktime

I'm having a seemingly simple problem with setting the default timezone in PHP. I'm trying to use `default_timezone_set()` to affect my `mktime()` function unsuccessfully.

In short, my server is set to UTC and I'm setting the timezone using `default_timezone_set()`, then calling `mktime()` to set a database date-time stamp.

However, the time in milliseconds that returns, comes back as UTC time. I echoed out the `default_timezone_get()` and it does indeed return as the timezone I'm setting and can't seem to determine why once I've successfully set the timezone that it fails to affect the `mktime()` function.

Am I missing something here? Isn't setting the default timezone supposed to affect all the date/time functions in PHP?

Comment: Have you ever heard of PHP's `DateTime` class?

Comment: DateTime is great, but [it doesn't do milliseconds](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: Also need to ensure that the datetime that you're populating `mktime()` from is the same as the the default timezone - see code snippet at http://3v4l.org/f9PmP

Answer (score 2):

Unix timestamps are *always* in UTC, You need to convert it to the the proper timezone *after* you get the timestamp.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? The manual, seems to suggest otherwise http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php#refsect1-function.mktime-errors

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)? From the [mktime manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

```
<?php
// Set the default timezone to use. Available as of PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Prints: July 1, 2000 is on a Saturday
echo "July 1, 2000 is on a " . date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));

// Prints something like: 2006-04-05T01:02:03+00:00
echo date('c', mktime(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2006));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well dumb me here, I just realized that I wasn't calling the timezone set from a third PHP file and of course, the date_default_timezone_set() function couldn't affect the separate file.

However, the answers and comments gave me some new ideas on how to handle it! Thank you all for the input.